# For Loop inside of a defined function

Tags: python

I'm having trouble getting the for loop in my weight function to work. The goal is to have a user input the number of PINs they want to evaluate and the program should prompt the user (a number of times) to input a 9-digit PIN. The 'weight' of the PIN is the sum of the absolute difference between
adjacent digits.(ex: 1234=abs(1-2)+abs(2-3)+abs(3-4)=3)

I got the program to ask the user about the PINs, but once I define weight, I'm having an issue.

After each input of the PIN I would like it to tell the user the 'weight'.
I am calling the functions in a for loop after the return:

```
for i in range(pin_num):
    prompt_user()
    weight(pin)



def weight(value):
    int_values = []  # Create an empty list to store the integers

    for char in value:
        int_values.append(int(char))  # Converts char to int and adds to list.
        weight=abs(int_values[0] - int_values[1]) + abs(int_values[1]
            - int_values[2])+ abs(int_values[2]
            - int_values[3])+abs(int_values[3] - int_values[4])+abs(int_values[4]
            - int_values[5])+abs(int_values[5] - int_values[6])+abs(int_values[6]
            - int_values[7])+abs(int_values[7] - int_values[8])
    #pin_weight = weight(pin)
        print('The PIN {} has a weight of {}'.format(pin,weight))
        return
```

Comment: What's the input it's failing on? And the correct result for that input? Why is there a comment at a different indentation, and why is the return inside the for loop?

Comment: Indentation matters, but also you want the function to just return a value. Then value = weight(pin) so you can write tests. You can print outside the function easily enough when you want to print. (Don't use the same name for different things, weight is both a function and a number.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to calculate `weight` on your first iteration of the loop:

```
for i in range(pin_num):
    prompt_user()
    weight(pin)



def weight(value):
    int_values = []  # Create an empty list to store the integers

    for char in value:
        int_values.append(int(char))  # Converts char to int and adds to list.

    #Calculates the weight after the loop has finished
    weight=abs(int_values[0] - int_values[1]) + abs(int_values[1]
        - int_values[2])+ abs(int_values[2]
        - int_values[3])+abs(int_values[3] - int_values[4])+abs(int_values[4]
        - int_values[5])+abs(int_values[5] - int_values[6])+abs(int_values[6]
        - int_values[7])+abs(int_values[7] - int_values[8])
    #pin_weight = weight(pin)
    print('The PIN {} has a weight of {}'.format(value,weight))
    return
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `print('The PIN {} has a weight of {}'.format(value,weight))`?

Answer (score 0):

@Chinyere, the issue with your code is an indent
You put the weight calculation inside the for loop which was incorrect

```
def weight(value):
    int_values = []  # Create an empty list to store the integers

    for char in value:
        int_values.append(int(char))  # Converts char to int and adds to list.
    # You put weight inside the for loop which was incorrect
    weight=abs(int_values[0] - int_values[1]) + \
        abs(int_values[1] - int_values[2]) + \
        abs(int_values[2] - int_values[3]) + \
        abs(int_values[3] - int_values[4]) + \
        abs(int_values[4] - int_values[5]) + \
        abs(int_values[5] - int_values[6]) + \
        abs(int_values[6] - int_values[7]) + \
        abs(int_values[7] - int_values[8])
    print('The PIN {} has a weight of {}'.format(pin,weight))
    return

for i in range(1):
    pin=input()
    weight(pin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print and return are inside the for loop. I'm pretty sure you don't want them to be so you need to reduce the leading spaces by four. Probably that calculation doesn't belong in there either.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you should take the calculation and code for printing out of the scope of the loop as others already mentioned. But you can do the same a little bit different way with `zip` like below -

```
def weight(value):
  w = 0
  for x, y in zip(value, value[1:]):
     w += abs(int(x) - int(y))

  <rest of your code>
```

Also you shouldn't use same name (`weight`) for function as well as variable